# "None" is being added at the bottom of the output

Tags: python

So whenever I run this code it outputs the values I need, but also a "None" value at the bottom
Why is that and how do I get rid of it?

```
insert = input("Insert Coin: ")

insert = int(insert)

amount_due = 50 - insert

def check_coins():
    if insert >= 0 and insert < 50:
        print("Amount Due:", amount_due)

    elif insert > 50:
        print(insert - 50)

    else:
        print("Amount Due:", amount_due)


print(check_coins())
```

Comment: How many `print` calls do you have? What do you expect each to output and why?

Comment: Don't `print` in the last line, just run `check_coins()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting `None` because of printing the function call, and the function is returning `None`

```
print(check_coins())
```

You need not require the print along with the function call.

Can you try the following:

```
insert = input("Insert Coin: ")

insert = int(insert)

amount_due = 50 - insert

def check_coins():
    if insert >= 0 and insert < 50:
        print("Amount Due:", amount_due)

    elif insert > 50:
        print(insert - 50)

    else:
        print("Amount Due:", amount_due)


check_coins()
```